# Kotlin Flows/Channel Concurrency Processing

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Since coroutine flows are sequential performing long running operations in the collector/consumer will cause the execution time to be the sum of the long running operations. To overcome this behavior and execute the long running operation concurrently in the collector/consumer I was wondering if the following code is conformed with coroutines and structured concurrency and also bug free, since it help me achieve the required behavior:

```
private suspend fun listenForResponses(
        channel: Channel<MyObject>,
        longRunningOperation: suspend (data: MyObject) -> Unit
    ) = withContext(currentCoroutineContext()) {
        channel.consumeEach { resultData ->
            Timber.i("onResponse: data: $resultData")
            launch {
                Timber.i("handle response")
                longRunningOperation(resultData)
                Timber.i("finished handling response")
            }
        }
    }
```

or for Flows:

```
private suspend fun listenForResponses(
        flow: Flow<MyObject>,
        longRunningOperation: suspend (data: MyObject) -> Unit
    ) = withContext(currentCoroutineContext()) {
        flow.onEach { resultData ->
            Timber.i("onResponse: data: $resultData")
            launch {
                Timber.i("handle response")
                longRunningOperation(resultData)
                Timber.i("finished handling response")
            }
        }.collect()
    }
```

Comment: I think this is generally fine, but it raises another question. If you don't want to queue items or use back-pressure, then why do you use channels/flows in the first place? Wouldn't it be easier to just invoke `scope.launch { onResponse() }` directly on the producer side instead of sending/emitting items?

Comment: Since it might break structured concurrency because if I cancel the job from which this function was called from the coroutine launched from scope.launch wont get cancelled as well

Comment: Yes, but it is exactly the same when using channels/flows, no? Channels/flows by design separate producers and consumers. If you want `longRunningOperation()` to be executed in the context of the requester, then my question about why you use channels/flows is even more important. It seems like you should just invoke `longRunningOperation()` directly.

Comment: Not sure I managed to follow. For example, take a use case that we emit event to a MutableSharedFlow that new item is added to a set. On that new added item I need to perform the long running operation, but many items can be added quickly and I want the long running operation to run concurrently on each of them.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your concern about cancelling. It sounded like you need to cancel the long running operation by the side that requested the operation. This is not possible with channels and flows as well, because you only send/emit to them and you can't cancel it afterwards. Ok, you provided an example with `MutableSharedFlow`. I assume there is only a single consumer (is it?) which run `launch()` for each item. How is it different then removing the flow entirely and replacing `emit()` with `scope.launch { longRunningOperation() }` where `scope` is the same scope you used for collection?

Comment: I dont want to be depend on any scope instance as this function is part of a larger system that contains many functions and operations that need to maintain structured concurrency and cooperative cancelation and not necessarily have access to the scope that started the system.

Comment: You don't have to depend on external scope. In both cases you have some external `scheduleDoingSomething()` function and this function either emits/sends or launches. The only difference is that you don't put items to channel/flow only to immediately pick them up on the other side. Such channel/flow does nothing here, only adds complexity.

Comment: What you describing is a very simple case which is not relevant for me. Maybe if you could read the following open issue you could better understand my issue:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1147
in which, in case of using flow, it is suggested to use flatMapMerge operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is structured correctly and will treat all errors from the long running operations. Bear in mind that an error that originates from a long running operation will:

- cancel the other long running operations that are running concurrently
- cancel the channel and its consumption OR cancel the flow collection
- prevent other operations from starting

If this is not the intended behaviour, I suggest using [`supervisorScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html?query=suspend%20fun%20%3CR%3E%20supervisorScope(block:%20suspend%20CoroutineScope.()%20-%3E%20R):%20R).

I would also recommend some improvements for readability and efficiency:

```kotlin
private suspend inline fun listenForResponses(
    channel: ReceiveChannel<MyObject>,
    crossinline longRunningOperation: (data: MyObject) -> Unit
) = coroutineScope {
    channel.consumeEach { resultData ->
        Timber.i("onResponse: data: $resultData")
        launch {
            Timber.i("handle response")
            longRunningOperation(resultData)
            Timber.i("finished handling response")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the explanation I was looking for! Thanks: )

Comment: You made me wonder - if the outer coroutine context that called this function is using supervised job than what you mentioned about the errors apply here? My guess is that is not since I think coroutineScope builder inherits the context from it's outer scope

Comment: The `coroutineScope` call actually adds a `Job` to the context that will act as a parent to all long running coroutines. When this job gets cancelled due to an error, all of the operations get cancelled as I mentioned in the answer, but the `SupervisorJob` from the calling function will still be running (which I am guessing is not really what you aimed for).